# Fax signal detection

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, voip, fax

Two scenarios are used to send a fax via a SIP session: [T.38](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3362) and [Pass-trough](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3362) [[another link]](http://what-when-how.com/voip/fax-pass-through-voip/). Detection of a fax-sending session is rather easy in first scenario (because fax transmission is explicitly mentioned in SDP body). In second method, a regular RTP call (G.711 Protocol) is established and after that, some beeps [(CNG and CDE)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice/session-initiation-protocol-sip/118647-technote-sip-00.html) are sending between two parties and they detects the fax call. I'm looking for a real-time method (deep learning, anything) to detect fax-initial-signal from a wave.

Comment: Tool/framework recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: I'm just looking for a keyword :-) Something like like "Keyword Spotting''. But a c++ library/framework is not for me. However, I deleted the line about framework from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Goertzel algorithm + time measurement. Looking into DTMF detectors code or better yet code from SpandDSP (there might be hints related to inteoperability) might give you more clues.